# Resource 'azurerm_sql_server.sql_server' not found for variable 'azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.name'

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I created sql with enable/disable options with `var.sql_server_enable`, but I have a problem about output. If the `var.sql_server_enable` is `0`, the `azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.name` is going to be `null` and I get the following error.

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sql_server" {
  count                        = "${var.sql_server_enable ? 1 : 0}"
  name                         = "${var.sql_server_name}"
  resource_group_name          = "${var.sql_server_resource_group_name}"
  location                     = "${var.sql_server_location}"
  version                      = "${var.sql_server_version}"
  administrator_login          = "${var.sql_server_admin_user}"
  administrator_login_password = "${var.sql_server_admin_pass}"
}
```

```
output "sql_server_name_output" {
  value = "${var.sql_server_enable == "1" ? azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.name : var.null }"
}
```

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error occurred:
        * module.hello.module.azure_sql_server_hello_staging.output.sql_server_name_output: Resource 'azurerm_sql_server.sql_server' not found for variable 'azurerm_sql_server.sql_server.name'
```

Comment: This is fixed in Terraform 0.12 but it's not doable in 0.11 or below. Upgrade to the latest Terraform version and this should go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could output
`value = "${var.sql_server_enable ? azurerm_sql_server.sql_server[0].name : var.null }"`. When you terraform apply, you could type "1" for true, "0" for false when you input values for variable "sql_server_enable".

This works for me with Terraform v0.12.6 + provider.azurerm v1.32.1, you can [upgrade it](https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html) if you need.

```
variable "sql_server_enable" {
  type = bool 

}

variable "null" {
  default = "this is empty"
}


resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sql_server" {
  count                        = "${var.sql_server_enable  ? 1 : 0}"
  name                         = "mysqlserver123qaz"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "mradministrator"
  administrator_login_password = "thisIsDog11"

}

output "sql_server_name_output" {
 value = "${var.sql_server_enable ? azurerm_sql_server.sql_server[0].name : var.null }"
 }
```

Result1
[image]
Result2
[image]
Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, but `sql_server_name_output` variable is used on the other module. It needs `string` value. Then i use `var.null` rather than `null`. After i follow your suggestion, I get another error below. Do you have any other suggestion?

```
Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on ../modules/azure_sql_server/output.tf line 9, in output "sql_server_name_output":
   9:   value = "${var.sql_server_enable ? azurerm_sql_server.sql_server[*].name : var.null }"
    |----------------
    | azurerm_sql_server.sql_server is tuple with 1 element
    | var.null is "null"
    | var.sql_server_enable is true
```

The other resource that needs `azurerm_sql_server.sql_server` is below.

```
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "sql_firewall_rule" {
  count               = "${var.sql_fw_enable == "1" ? 1 : 0}"
  name                = "${var.sql_fw_rule_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.sql_fw_rule_resource_group_name}"
  server_name         = "${azurerm_sql_server.sql_server}"
  start_ip_address    = "${var.sql_fw_rule_start_ip}"
  end_ip_address      = "${var.sql_fw_rule_end_ip}"
}
```

Comment: Please re-check my edit and I change `azurerm_sql_server.sql_server[*].name` to `azurerm_sql_server.sql_server[0].name`, and I test it with `var.null` though I have not used it as a module, let me know if this works. And what's your terraform version.